# When using React, how can I make a general JavaScript event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, reactjs

I'm, using React and I'm becoming confused as to how I can implement a general Javascript event emitter.  I would like to attach React to an event emitter which updates the UI when a particular event occurs.

For example, a user can become logged out in a number of different ways, all of which have a shared UI change: The user explicitly presses "Log Out", the server logs the user out and sends a message, the connection was dropped and the app knows to treat this as a log out, etc...

I would like to send each of these "LoggedOut" events, which have a shared UI change, to a single event listener which then calls the correct React callback function.

Is this something which should be done, and if so, how do I do this properly?

Comment: It sounds like you want something like [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html). React itself doesn't really dictate one way or another.

Comment: This is totally Flux. You should take a look at it.

Comment: You can use [Cortex](https://github.com/mquan/cortex) for that kind of management.

Comment: Awesome, Flux is exactly what I was looking for.  I've looked over Cortex, and while it seems great, I prefer to get development experience with the Flux architecture before I move to a technology which abstracts the details.